# From transaction data to list of sets in an efficient way

Tags: python, performance, list, pandas, set

I have a csv file with transaction data of the following form

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'OrderID':[1,1,1,1,2,2], 'ItemID':[1,2,3,4,1,2]})
print(df)
   ItemID  OrderID
0       1        1
1       2        1
2       3        1
3       4        1
4       1        2
5       2        2
```

I want to obtain a list that contains for every OrderID the sets of items.

This can be obtained with

```
df.groupby('OrderID').apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'])).tolist()
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

However, on a csv file with 9 million rows this takes some time. Thus, I'm wondering if there is a faster way?
I'm interested in any solution with pandas or that operates directly on a .csv-file

---

First of all I want to thank you guys, for your awesome input!
I took a sample of 50000 OrderIds (and the corresponding items) from my real data and applied several of the methods from to the data set.
And here are the results

[image: BenchmarkResults]

Note that I used the updated version of the pir programm.
So the winner is divakar, even if we only consider the list of sets output.

On my whole data set, his faster set approach has a duration of 5.05 seconds and his faster list based approach a duration of only 2.32s.
That is a huge gain from the initial 115 seconds!
Thanks again!

Comment: Huh? it seems to me you just created a set out of both columns?

Comment: hmm, yes and I think that's what I want to do. Do you have a simpler way? Maybe I'm stuck in my way of thinking :)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Would `OrderID` be sorted like it is in the sample?

Comment: In general not, but of course it's possible to do this in a preprocessing step when fetching data from the data base

Comment: A new idea came to me.  I've updated my post.

Comment: Good to see some improvement there from the initial 115 sec!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Using array splitting and `set` -

```
def divakar_v1(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = a[:,1].argsort() # Use .argsort(kind='mergesort') to keep order
    cut_idx = np.nonzero(a[sidx[1:],1] > a[sidx[:-1],1])[0]+1
    out = np.split(a[sidx,0], cut_idx)
    return list(map(set,out))
```

**Approach #2 :** Using iterative array slicing and `set` -

```
def divakar_v2(df):
    data = df.values
    a = data[data[:,1].argsort()] # Use .argsort(kind='mergesort') to keep order
    stop = np.append(np.nonzero(a[1:,1] > a[:-1,1])[0]+1,a.size)
    start = np.append(0, stop[:-1])
    out_set = [set(a[start[i]:stop[i],0]) for i in range(len(start))]
    return out_set
```

---

Given that per `'OrderID'`, we would have unique/distinct elements in `'ItemID'`, we would have two more approaches skipping the use of `set()` and thus giving us a list of lists as output. These are listed next.

**Approach #3 :** Using array splitting and `list of lists as o/p` -

```
def divakar_v3(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = a[:,1].argsort() # Use .argsort(kind='mergesort') to keep order
    cut_idx = np.nonzero(a[sidx[1:],1] > a[sidx[:-1],1])[0]+1
    out = np.split(a[sidx,0], cut_idx)
    return list(map(list,out))
```

**Approach #4 :** Using iterative array slicing and `list of lists as o/p` -

```
def divakar_v4(df):
    data = df.values
    a = data[data[:,1].argsort()] # Use .argsort(kind='mergesort') to keep order
    stop = np.append(np.nonzero(a[1:,1] > a[:-1,1])[0]+1,a.size)
    start = np.append(0, stop[:-1])
    a0 = a[:,0].tolist()
    return [a0[start[i]:stop[i]] for i in range(len(start))]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [145]: np.random.seed(123)
     ...: N = 100000
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30,size=(N,2)))
     ...: df.columns = ['ItemID','OrderID']
     ...: 

In [146]: %timeit divakar_v1(df)
     ...: %timeit divakar_v2(df)
     ...: %timeit divakar_v3(df)
     ...: %timeit divakar_v4(df)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 21.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: your second approach seems to be incredible. Can the others confirm? could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I chack output of your both functions and it return something another as another solutions. Something wrong? I test it if N = 50, N=100

Comment: for my data set, the results are exactly the same, even when sampling randomly

Comment: @jezrael Tested on `N= 50` and results are identical from these two approaches. Doesn't look like there's any discrepnancy. Or could it be the order that I am not maintaining with appproach 2, so test out with `kind='mergesort'`?

Comment: I think your solutions return same output, but if compare with my or pir solutions, there is difference.

Comment: I test it with `30`: `[{17, 11, 14, 15}, {12}, {20}, {2, 28}, {0}, {17, 1}, {9}, {3}, {5}, {2}, {29}, {24, 9}, {4}, {23}, {10}, {7}, {22}, {1}, {19}, {25, 2}, {2, 20}, {16}]` your return `[{4}, {22, 6}, {27, 3, 28, 13}, {8}, {16}, {10}, {20}, {7, 15}, {19}, {0}, {1}, {0}, {0}, {29}, {0, 6}, {25}, {2, 28}, {21}, {17}, {15}, {27}, {3}, {14}]`

Comment: @jezrael Ah I got it! Your test setup has `OrderID` as the first col! Mine assumes first col as `ItemID` as used for OP's sample.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Updated with two more approaches that gives list of lists as o/p. So, check out how `approach #4` times against the other solutions for your actual input setup given per 'OrderID', we would have unique/distinct elements in 'ItemID', otherwise I think others have better solutions that deal with `set`.

Comment: yeah, I had the same issue here :) the array creation unfortunately put the ItemId as first column ;)

Answer (score 5):

***new method***
`defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pir(df):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for n, g in df.groupby('OrderID').ItemID:
        d[n].update(g.values.tolist())

    return list(d.values())
```

***sample***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(OrderID=np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000000),
                       ItemID=np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000000)))
```

[image]

---

***old method***

```
uo, io = np.unique(df.OrderID.values, return_inverse=True)
ui, ii = np.unique(df.ItemID.values, return_inverse=True)

def gu(i):
    return set(ui[ii[io == i]].tolist())

[gu(i) for i in range(len(uo))]

[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

---

***old timing***
*code:*

```
def pir(df):
    uo, io = np.unique(df.OrderID.values, return_inverse=True)
    ui, ii = np.unique(df.ItemID.values, return_inverse=True)

    def gu(i):
        return set(ui[ii[io == i]].tolist())

    return [gu(i) for i in range(len(uo))]

def jez(df):
    arr = df.groupby('OrderID')['ItemID'].unique().values
    return [set(v) for v in arr]

def div(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = a[:,1].argsort(kind='mergesort')
    cut_idx = np.nonzero(a[sidx[1:],1] > a[sidx[:-1],1])[0]+1
    out = np.split(a[sidx,0], cut_idx)
    return list(map(set,out))

def quik(df):
    return df.groupby('OrderID').apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'])).tolist()
```

*with sample data*
[image]

*with more data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(OrderID=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10000),
                       ItemID=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10000)))
```

[image]

*even more data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(OrderID=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10000000),
                       ItemID=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10000000)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am wrong in my timings, I try it again.

Comment: on my data set, this takes 50% longer than my or jez's solution

Comment: pandas beats numpy? I cant believe it ;)

Comment: @jezrael even with limited uniqueness... yours is way quicker on larger set.

Comment: only wanted to mention this, since jez's solution is on artificial data faster than mine. But nice work here

Comment: yes, it depends of real data. ;) super solutions ;)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 this is a regular occurrence. we do this alot

Comment: @piRsquared could you also include my solution in the benchmarks? I'm not yet sure which answer to accept. All are excellent, but none really increases the performance ;)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 sure

Comment: I assume the call `pir(df)` should in fact be `pir2(df)` right before the __old method__ paragraph

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 yes. Whoops

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html), then convert to `numpy array` and last to `set` by `list comprehension`:

```
arr = df.groupby('OrderID')['ItemID'].unique().values
print (arr)
[array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64) array([1, 2], dtype=int64)]

print ([set(v) for v in arr])
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

EDIT Faster is use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) in `apply`:

```
print (df.groupby('OrderID').apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'].unique())).tolist())
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30,size=(N,2)))
df.columns = ['OrderID','ItemID']

def pir(df):
    uo, io = np.unique(df.OrderID.values, return_inverse=True)
    ui, ii = np.unique(df.ItemID.values, return_inverse=True)
    def gu(i):
        return set(ui[ii[io == i]].tolist())
    return [gu(i) for i in range(len(uo))]

def divakar(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = a[:,1].argsort(kind='mergesort')
    cut_idx = np.nonzero(a[sidx[1:],1] > a[sidx[:-1],1])[0]+1
    out = np.split(a[sidx,0], cut_idx)
    return list(map(set,out))
```

```
In [120]: %timeit (df.groupby('OrderID')
                     .apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'].unique())).tolist())
10 loops, best of 3: 92.7 ms per loop


In [121]: %timeit (df.groupby('OrderID').apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'])).tolist())
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop

In [122]: %timeit ([set(v) for v in df.groupby('OrderID')['ItemID'].unique().values])
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [123]: %timeit (list(map(set,df.groupby('OrderID')['ItemID'].unique().values)))
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [124]: %timeit (pir(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 276 ms per loop

In [125]: %timeit (divakar(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 190 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm running benchmark and will comment later.

Comment: Sure, I think it depends of real data - sizes of groups, uniqueness... But it seems my solution is a bit faster.

Comment: On the whole data set you solution is 4 seconds faster (1.52 instead of 1.56). However, when choosing subsets of the data(using head and a random subsample), your solution may even be a bit slower. On a sample of size 100.000 I find 4.66s to 4.72s. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing to the unique function

Comment: I think i found faster solution - `print (df.groupby('OrderID').apply(lambda x: set(x['ItemID'].unique())).tolist())`. How it works with real data?

Comment: on my dataset this decreases performance. But this is easily explainable :) The data set only contains distinct items per order. So the additional overhead must reduce performance.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 If the dataset is such that per OrderID, all elements are already unique/distinct, then you won't need the uniqueness operation done by `set()`. So, just a list of lists would suffice as the final output, right?

Comment: @divakar, currently I'm working on an implementation of the apriori algorithm that uses list of sets as baskets. However, it seems that my implementation also works with lists of lists. So that could work to.